# Webpack Vue component with css <style> tags fails to build with Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader, primevue

Starting with a clean vue project, I was having issues building .vue components from PrimeVue.
These are ready made components and should really not fail to build.

Everytime I try to build, it fails to do so, and seems to fail with the line pointer at the start of the CSS styles.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/primevue/components/slider/Slider.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/primevue/components/slider/Slider.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&) 340:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (340:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
|
> .p-slider {
|   position: relative;
| }
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/components/slider/Slider.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& 1:0-119 1:135-138 1:140-256 1:140-256
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/components/slider/Slider.vue
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/slider.js
 @ ./myproject/components/Test.js
 @ ./myproject/components/App.js
 @ ./myproject/main.js
```

This is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: 'main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

What is causing this error, as I am importing the components correctly as stated by the PrimeVue documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a rule in the webpack config to send the `.vue` files for processing to `vue-loader` is not enough.

You need to specify how to handle `.css` files too, and this then gets applied to  tags in a `.vue` file as well. Without this rule, it will not know what to do with the `<style>` blocks, even if you dont plan on using the .css file part of this.

Update the rules section of the `webpack.config.js` with the following:

```
rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
            // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Also make sure that `vue-style-loader` and `css-loader` are installed in package.json.

More information can be found at the [manual installation section](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup) of the vue-loader documentation, specifically the code example under *'A more complete example webpack config will look like this.'*

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to cache the .vue files because they will slow down your build time in big projects.

```
// snippet from https://github.com/unic/darvin-webpack-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack/settings/javascript-vue/index.js

const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require('vue-loader');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const path = require('path');
const ROOT_PATH = process.cwd();

const CACHE_PATH = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'tmp/cache');

const VUE_VERSION = require('vue/package.json').version;
const VUE_LOADER_VERSION = require('vue-loader/package.json').version;

const dev = {
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                cacheDirectory: path.join(CACHE_PATH, 'vue-loader'),
                cacheIdentifier: [
                    process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
                    webpack.version,
                    VUE_VERSION,
                    VUE_LOADER_VERSION,
                ].join('|'),
            },
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
],
resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    },
};
```

Comment: Although not relevant to the question, it's useful to know, so thanks for sharing @tfr

Comment: I've figured out this error, but now presented with a new one, could you take a look and see if you have any tips? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021441/webpack-build-error-cant-resolve-subcomponents-within-a-primevue-ui-component