# Webpack Build Error: Can't resolve subcomponents within a PrimeVue UI component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader, primevue

I am unable to build certain PrimeVue UI components with webpack.

I have tried several components, and all the basic ones work fine, but as soon as I try and use a component that requires a sub-component, webpack fails to build. I experienced this so far with the Breadcrumb and PanelMenu components.

The error is:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './PanelMenuSub' in '/my-application-directory/node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu'
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 27:0-42 86:24-36
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue
 @ ./node_modules/primevue/panelmenu.js
 @ ./interface/html5/vue-components/Menu.js
 @ ./interface/html5/vue-components/App.js
 @ ./interface/html5/vue-main.js
```

My webpack config is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: 'vue-main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'vue-main.bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            // the below will apply to both plain `.js` files AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
            // the below will apply to both plain `.css` files AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

The component is used exactly as described in the documentation.

What could be causing this? The same is happening with the Breadcrumb component, except it can't find the BreadcrumbItem component. I checked the node_modules directory and the files are there.

Is this a webpack config file problem, a PrimeVue bug, or a user (me) error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that your full config without babel? I would try to resolve properly.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': res('src'),
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    modules: [res('node_modules')],
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: [res('node_modules')]
  }
```

Comment: yes im not using babel. Do you need to? If so, why. Would like to keep it as lean as possible. This is used in a backbone/jQuery project as a gradual transformation to vue.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could explain the different things you put in resolve and why they would fix it? Going to try it now and im reading the link you posted, but it would help to understand

Comment: So it seems to work now... but no idea why. So if I understand correctly, this is basically just telling webpack to go look in node_modules for things. But why is that needed? The first component PanelMenu was found perfectly fine, but its sub component (in the same node_modules directory) could not be found. So is this fixing the issue, or just covering up a problem with a bypass?

Comment: You just have to define where webpack should resolve the modules. But..

if you are not very familiar with the build tools and already working productively I highly recommend using the Vue-Cli. Otherwise you will be busy with browser compatibility and bundling for a very long time. https://cli.vuejs.org/

Otherwise you can study a full featured up-to-date webpack boilerplate here -> https://darvin.dev

Comment: @darvin, I tried to go the webpack route as I read vue-cli makes it more complex by doing too much for you. My manager does not even want to use webpack, as it takes away from the control of a manual build. but it seemed better than the vue-cli which was more blackbox. We will also need to convert some of our complex manual processes, so figured webpack would be better than vue-cli?

Comment: Btw, @tfr, apparently not recommended to resolve node_modules. but no idea why. `"It's not good to resolve node_modules using path.resolve. This can cause problems with sub-dependencies. Use the string 'node_modules' instead. [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules' ], "`

Comment: you always have to watch in webpack which folder you resolve and which one you exclude (e.g in babel). thats the reason why you should work with aliases instead of relative paths, but its a 3rd party component. If you want make your code run on all browsers  (also IE11) and always want to code with the latest ECMA Script Definition, you should checkout babel. Darvin compiles dual for modern and legacy browser (polyfilled and babel transpiled).

Comment: IE11 is blocked in our browser matrix, so that wont be an issue. Since that move was made, we started going more ES6. and I sort of understand what you are saying, but this was a relative path in the current directory, so why would that fail. See here: https://unpkg.com/browse/primevue@2.0.0-beta.1/components/panelmenu/ and https://unpkg.com/browse/primevue@2.0.0-beta.1/components/panelmenu/PanelMenu.vue

Comment: vue-cli is an easy and maintainable all-inclusive build. if you going with your own build setting and using full featured webstack, you have to calculate some weeks for it.

Comment: If you starting a new longterm project go vue-cli 4 with typescript.
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/

Otherwise you're probably outdated faster than backbone. Darvin ist also Vue-Typescript and open setting.

Comment: Can you customize vue-cli to exclude certain components from a build based on a software "version type" we currently do this with requirejs. I was hoping webpack might be able to, hence that choice.

Comment: its not a new project sadly, its bringing vue slowly into the backbone application. typescript mixed into the existing app would get messy I think.

Comment: plus, I thought webpack was now supposed to be zero config, so it seems odd why something as common as node_modules needs resolving :/

Comment: please ask this question in a new topic. requirejs was cool but late back, that all handled now by webpack dynamic imports and magic comments. please create new topics for more webpack questions.
https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments

Comment: zero config ^^ nope. I would say config only.